# replace all special characters with a backslash plus special character in Unix Shell

Tags: bash

I need to replace the special character which is not alphanumeric with a backslash in a string.

How do i do it in Bash? My version is 4.1

I can capture the special character the plus symbol using the following regex

```
([^[:alnum:]])
```

For example, applied to the string

```
Alan5+6imson
```

I can do

```
$ echo $orig_str |sed 's/([^[:alnum:]])/\\1/g'
Alan5+6imson
```

I need the output as

```
Alan5\+6imson
```

How can I replace it in Bash?

I tried the above regex but not sure how to perform a replacement.

Do i need to use some other tool or something like `sed`?

Comment: A mention for `cat -v` which will replace non-printables with slash codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
echo "$orig_str" | sed 's/\([^[:alnum:]]\)/\\\1/g'
```

or:

```
echo "$orig_str" | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g'
```

Comment: Thanks i just couldn't figure this out Thanks a ton